# Which features affect my Keras model the most?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm using Keras to classify my data. The input has 11 columns, and I'm curious to get a hint of which ones influence the Keras model the most - I suspect a few of the variables are not good predictors at all and I want to see to what extent Keras detect that.

My code is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu',input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(target_len, activation='softmax', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])
model.fit(master,target,validation_split=0.3)
```

And then I use the following code to get the weights and biases:

```
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
```

I suspect I could get the answer from the weights and biases somehow but I'm not 100% sure of the maths and logic behind it. My ideal result would be something like an array of numbers where each number signifies the relative importance of corresponding column in the original input data.

Comment: you could try implementing this technique in keras/python: https://www.r-bloggers.com/variable-importance-in-neural-networks/

Comment: I'll have a try at that. Unfortunately the scientific articles he refers to are not public (or, you have to pay for them)